# Ajax `<div>` after refresh data not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to update `<div>` after updating the data in the database, but after `<div>` is refreshing, it doesn't show the data. Here's my code:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="receivedHere" style="width: 100%;">

  @foreach($compose as $compose)
  @if($compose->active == 1)
    ......
     <input type="hidden" id="id" value="{{ $compose->id }}">
     <img src="/public/images/EyePublic.svg" 
     onclick="changeComposer('0','{{ $compose->id }}')"></span>
    ......
  @else($compose->active == 0)
   ....
       <input type="hidden" id="id" value="{{ $compose->id }}">
       <img src="/public/images/EyePrivate.svg" 
       onclick="changeComposer('1','{{ 
       $compose->id }}')"></span>
    .....

  @endif
 @endforeach

</div>
```

and my ajax code is

```
function changeComposer(argument, id) {
  var link = "{{ URL::to('/') }}/public/images/settingLoader.gif";
  document.getElementById('receivedHere').innerHTML = '<center><img 
  src="'+link+'"></center>'; //for replacing the div to img after click and image will remove after ajax success.

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{URL::to('/')}}/updateComposer",
    data: {id : id, update : argument},
    success: function(){
      $("#receivedHere").load(" #receivedHere");
    }
  });
 }
```

updated part is working, but after success, reloads the `div` and taking the updated data is not showing... Any suggestion?

And my controller for updated is

```
public function updateComposer(Request $request) {
    $user_id = UserGratitude::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    if($user_id){
        UserGratitude::where('id', $request->id)
            ->update([
                'is_active' => $request->update
            ]);
        return response('success', 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: So `updateComposer` returns the content to be placed in the div?

Comment: ill post my controller again, please check the updated

Comment: please check the updated questions... @Musa

Comment: `@foreach($compose as $compose)` same variable ? why ?

Comment: I don't have a problem here, it works fine like this, but from now on I'll try to use separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html` method like that

```
$("#receivedHere").html('<center><img src="'+link+'"></center>')
```

Here is the JS flow

```
//show loading is in progress    
$("#receivedHere").html('<center><img src="'+link+'"></center>')

//make ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{URL::to('/')}}/updateComposer",
    data: {id : id, update : argument},
    success: function(data){
        //parse your data if needed

        //show data by updating DOM

        $("#receivedHere").html("<p>Received data</p>");

    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: this part is for after on click, the .gif image will display to show that the data is in the process, after the success it stops and (will?) take the updated data

Comment: Updated my answer above to reflect all JS flow

Comment: how can i use foreach loop inside `ajax.html`

Comment: It is a different question already but you can use a template engine like handlebars https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html.  Another way is to use jQuery to create a piece of HTML and inject it in DOM. Do not forget to mark my answer as answered if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a actual url in your call to `.load()` if you want to filter out a portion of the page.
You can use location to get the url of the current page.

```
$("#receivedHere").load(location.href + " #receivedHere");
```

Comment: this is not working either, still giving the same error i got before

Comment: like, it does refresh the page but not showing data... sorry for getting wrong